# How to define the meaning of the action of a particular object? (in Adobe Flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, text

While I learned how to create a program, I wrote a simple definition for my "button" (in Adobe Flash): it can be pressed. So, now I want the following: after pressing this button some text appears on the screen. I have a main package, `file.as`, a package for my Button `file.as` and `file.fla`, where I draw the button. Can you help me, please, in simple steps?

Answer (score 1):

afrer click your button you can create textfield and add it

```
> var myText:TextField = new TextField();
> myText.text = "button is clicked";
> addChild(myText);
```

it's very simple

Comment: Thank you very much!! I know, it's should be a simple quest)) But I'm only learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a button "myButton" and a text field "myTextField":

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    myTextField.text = "here is my text";
}
```